# Django name 'request' is not defined while filtering based on users

Tags: python, django, authentication

In Django I am trying to filter some posts based on a user. I have looked it up and found that the way to do it (or the way that was suggested), is to use request.user, but when I do this I get an error saying `name 'request' is not defined`

View:

```
class MyPost(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "public/list.html"
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyPost, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['post'] = Post.objects.filter(live=True, user=request.user)
        return context
```

I am unsure if this is the way to do it or not, but I couldn't find anywhere that had good documentation on this. If anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: `user = self.rest.user`

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyPost, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['post'] = Post.objects.filter(live=True, user=self.request.user)  # used self for object reference
    return context
```

I would also recommend to subclass your ListView from [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) to ensure the view is only accessible for logged in user. You can do it like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyPost(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
   # rest of the code
```

Comment: Yes that has solved the error, but getting a ```Cannot resolve keyword 'post' into field.```

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace please?